# Не могу разобраться с сигналами, слотами, и многопоточкой PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Я начинающий питонист. Есть некоторый проект, текущая задача которого - парсить в режиме real-time HTTP-ответы сервера из списка (циклически, постоянно), выводя в UI актуальную инфу как о текущем URL, так и в целом, какие адреса возвращали неприемлемые для нас ответы, а какие приемлемые.

UI обязателен.

В целом всё делается приемлемо, вот только функция работает в том же потоке, что и UI, и фризит весь интерфейс до момента окончания цикла.

Перелопатил N-ное количество разных источников, попробовал, все дела. Нужный поток есть, в нём можно что-то выполнить, вот только как передать сигнал из UI для старта функции, так и заставить UI выводить всё, что нам надо - не получается.

Бекап с потоком не сохранился (вернее, пришёл в абсолютную негодность в результате экспериментов), но есть первоначальный вариант. Его и прикладываю.

```
from Souce.ui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import urllib
#Объявление UI
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_RequestCheckerUI()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Cобытие нажатия на кнопку
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.reqCheck)
    #объявление функции, переменных, массива.
    def reqCheck(self):
        self.ui.textBrowser.setText("")
        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText("")
        stroki = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()
        mas=stroki.split('\n')
        result_good=''
        result_bad=''
        #Цикл, который собирает и выводит ответы сервера
        for stroka in mas:
            url = (stroka)
            reqCode = urllib.request.urlopen(url).getcode()
            self.ui.textEdit_2.append(url)
            reqCodeStr3 = str(reqCode)
            self.ui.textEdit_2.append(reqCodeStr3)
            if reqCode == 200:
                reqCodeStr = str(reqCode)
                result_good = url+'------'+reqCodeStr+'\n'
                self.ui.textBrowser.append(result_good)
            elif reqCode == 301 or 302 or 303 or 304 or 305 or 300 or 400 or 401 or 402 or 403 or 404 or 405 or 500 or 501 or 502 or 503 or 504 or 505:
                reqCodeStr2 = str(reqCode)
                result_bad = url+'------'+reqCodeStr2+'\n'
                self.ui.textBrowser_2.append(result_bad)

#UI запуск
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ниже Souce.ui.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '1ts.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_RequestCheckerUI(object):
    def setupUi(self, RequestCheckerUI):
        RequestCheckerUI.setObjectName("RequestCheckerUI")
        RequestCheckerUI.resize(1027, 827)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("nani?!")
        RequestCheckerUI.setWindowIcon(icon)
        RequestCheckerUI.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(RequestCheckerUI)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 680, 411, 71))
        self.textEdit.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 650, 341, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.CheckPB = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.CheckPB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 760, 1021, 21))
        self.CheckPB.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.CheckPB.setObjectName("CheckPB")
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 700, 64, 31))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 710, 121, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 710, 47, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 700, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 311, 481))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 100, 141, 20))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 120, 256, 481))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(343, 70, 41, 551))
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.line.setLineWidth(7)
        self.line.setMidLineWidth(7)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 100, 171, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 120, 256, 481))
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 100, 161, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(7, 610, 991, 20))
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.line_2.setLineWidth(7)
        self.line_2.setMidLineWidth(7)
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 991, 20))
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.line_3.setLineWidth(7)
        self.line_3.setMidLineWidth(7)
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.verticalScrollBar_input = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalScrollBar_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 120, 16, 481))
        self.verticalScrollBar_input.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar_input.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar_input")
        self.verticalScrollBar_good = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalScrollBar_good.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 120, 16, 481))
        self.verticalScrollBar_good.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar_good.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar_good")
        self.verticalScrollBar_bad = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalScrollBar_bad.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(980, 120, 16, 481))
        self.verticalScrollBar_bad.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar_bad.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar_bad")
        RequestCheckerUI.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(RequestCheckerUI)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1027, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        RequestCheckerUI.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(RequestCheckerUI)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        RequestCheckerUI.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(RequestCheckerUI)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(RequestCheckerUI)

    def retranslateUi(self, RequestCheckerUI):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        RequestCheckerUI.setWindowTitle(_translate("RequestCheckerUI", "RequestCheckerUI 0.0001b"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("RequestCheckerUI", "Вставьте URL для проверки по одному на каждую строку."))
        self.lcdNumber.setToolTip(_translate("RequestCheckerUI", "<html><head/><body><p>Цикл начинается с нуля.</p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("RequestCheckerUI", "Цикл повторяется уже"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("RequestCheckerUI", "-й раз"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("RequestCheckerUI", "Старт/Стоп"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("RequestCheckerUI", "Текущий статус проверки"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("RequestCheckerUI", "Хорошие HTTP-ответы сервера"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("RequestCheckerUI", "Плохие HTTP-ответы сервера"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("RequestCheckerUI", "Проверка урлов"))
```

Comment: 1) Чтобы не фризилось гуи, выполнения нужно делать в отдельном потоке 2) Проверка `reqCode == 301 or 302 or 303 or 304 or 305 or 300 or 400 or 401 or 402 or 403 or 404 or 405 or 500 or 501 or 502 or 503 or 504 or 505` сделает не то, что вы ожидались

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужно в отдельном потоке. Но я не могу запустить функцию, находящуюся в том самом отдельном потоке из UI. Равно как и передать данные обратно.

Comment: @AgeofCreations вы можете поделиться модулем Souce.ui.py ?

Comment: Каким образом будет удобнее это сделать? В плане удобства для Вас, разумеется.

Comment: @AgeofCreations таким же как и 'первоначальный вариант', который вы  опубликовали.

Comment: @S.Nick Добавил в конец вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляю пример гуи, в котором в отдельном потоке выполняется работа с сетью, а в главный поток приходят сообщения через сигнал:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

# Для быстрого запуска лучше заменить на абсолютные импорты
from PyQt5.Qt import *


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


import sys
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class MyCheckUrlThread(QThread):
    about_check_url = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, urls):
        super().__init__()

        self.urls = urls

    def run(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            try:
                code = urlopen(url).getcode()
            except Exception as e:
                # Пусть будет исключение
                code = str(e)

            self.about_check_url.emit('{}------{}'.format(url, code))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.urls = QTextEdit()
        self.urls.setText("""\
https://ru.stackoverflow.com
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893436/
https://google.com
http://ya.ru
http://not_found_site.123
""")

        self.result = QTextBrowser()

        self.pb_check = QPushButton('Check')
        self.pb_check.clicked.connect(self._on_click_check)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.urls)
        layout.addWidget(self.result)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.pb_check)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.thread = MyCheckUrlThread(urls=None)
        self.thread.about_check_url.connect(self._on_about_check_url)

    def _on_click_check(self):
        urls = self.urls.toPlainText().strip().split('\n')

        self.thread.urls = urls
        self.thread.start()

    def _on_about_check_url(self, text):
        self.result.append(text)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    
    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

Возможна модификация потока, добавление других сигналов, например сигнал на плохой код http, или на логирование выполнения запросов и т.п.

В сигнале можно передавать и объекты, а не только строки. Так что, в потоке можно составить список или словарь и его отдавать в главный поток

Кроме того, потоки умеют сообщать свое состояние через сигналы [started](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#started) и [finished](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#finished), а это поможет проконтролировать выполнение потока, например при `started` заблокировать кнопку, а при `finished` разблокировать и сообщить юзеру.

---

#### UPD.

[Обновил код](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/261447f218ff2cedc3cfc3c4911d49dd79709d94/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/check_urls.py#L37):

```
import traceback
import sys

from typing import List

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QMessageBox, QPushButton,
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt

import requests


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


session = requests.session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0'


class CheckUrlThread(QThread):
    about_check_url = pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, urls: List[str] = None):
        super().__init__()

        self.urls = urls if urls else []

    def run(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            try:
                rs = session.get(url)
                code = rs.status_code

            except Exception as e:
                # Пусть будет исключение
                code = e

            code = str(code)

            self.about_check_url.emit(url, code)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.urls = QPlainTextEdit()

        headers = ["URL", "CODE"]

        self.result_table = QTableWidget()
        self.result_table.setColumnCount(len(headers))
        self.result_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)
        self.result_table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.result_table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.result_table.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(0, 200)

        self.pb_check = QPushButton('Check')
        self.pb_check.clicked.connect(self._on_click_check)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.urls)
        layout.addWidget(self.result_table)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.pb_check)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.thread = CheckUrlThread()
        self.thread.about_check_url.connect(self._on_about_check_url)
        self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.pb_check.setEnabled(False))
        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.pb_check.setEnabled(True))

    def _on_click_check(self):
        urls = self.urls.toPlainText().strip().splitlines()

        self.result_table.clearContents()
        self.result_table.setRowCount(0)

        for url in urls:
            row = self.result_table.rowCount()
            self.result_table.setRowCount(row + 1)

            self.result_table.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(url))
            self.result_table.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem())

        self.thread.urls = urls
        self.thread.start()

    def _on_about_check_url(self, url: str, code: str):
        for item in self.result_table.findItems(url, Qt.MatchCaseSensitive):
            row = item.row()
            self.result_table.item(row, 1).setText(code)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    text = '\n'.join([
        'https://ru.stackoverflow.com',
        'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893436/',
        'https://google.com',
        'http://ya.ru',
        'http://not_found_site.123',
    ])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.urls.setPlainText(text)
    mw.resize(800, 600)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вау. Круто, лаконично. А я, блин, велосипедов понапридумывал, пока пытался. Спасибо. И за полезный постскриптум.